# How to sequentially display items list with React

Tags: reactjs, css-animations, array.prototype.map

I want to display an entire array of milestones, but I need to be sequentially.
For example: first appear `milestones[0]`, then `milestones[1]`, then `milestones[2]`, and so on.

So I have a `milestones.map()` to create a card for each milestone and tried to add a `settimeout` to "slow down" the `.map()`, but this doesn't work.

Being more graphic, [I have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyUg9.gif) and [I need this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAzSQ.gif)

This is the code I have:

```
return (
   <TransitionGroup className='listOfMilestones'>
       {milestones.map((milestone) => {
          return (
             <CSSTransition
             key={milestone.id}
             timeout={500}
             classNames='eachMilestone'
             >
                <MilestoneCard
                  ageRange={ageRange}
                  id={milestone.id}
                  title={milestone.title}
                  answer={milestone.answer}
                 />
             </CSSTransition>
           }
      }
   </TransitionGroup>
)
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.eachMilestone-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transform: translateY(40px);
}

.eachMilestone-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  transition: 500ms ease-in;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So it seems like you need to timeout to increase for each item in `milestones`.  Maybe use the index from `map` and do something like

```
timeout={500 + 100 * i}
```

The first item would have a 500ms timeout, the second 600 and so on.  You can tweak that to delay as you intend.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't thought about it, but I tried and didn't work